# Can I add a variable to $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two functions:

```
function animateOpen(){
    var originalPosition = $(this).css("left");
    var distance = $(this).getHorzontalDistanceToCenter();
    $(this).animate("left", "+="+distance);
    $('#button').click( function (){
        $(this).animate("left", originalPosition+"px");
    });
}
function animateClose(){
    $('#button').click();
}
```

I want to convert this code to the bottom form (to remove the dependency on button):

```
function animateClose(){
    $(this).animate("left", originalPosition+"px");
}
function animateOpen(){
    var originalPosition = $(this).css("left");
    var distance = $(this).getHorzontalDistanceToCenter();
    $(this).animate("left", "+="+distance);
}
```

The problem is, how does `animateClose` get the `originalPosition`? Can I somehow put it in `$(this)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the original position using `$(this).data('original_left', my_value)`

And afterwards, get the saved value with `$(this).data('original_left')`

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a closure and share `originalPosition`:

```
(function(){
    var originalPosition;
    function animateClose(){
        $(this).animate("left", originalPosition+"px");
    }
    function animateOpen(){
        originalPosition = $(this).css("left");
        var distance = $(this).getHorzontalDistanceToCenter();
        $(this).animate("left", "+="+distance);
    }
    window.animateClose = animateClose;
    window.animateOpen = animateOpen;
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

Call `$(this).data('some name', value)`.

You can get the value later by calling `$(this).data('some name')`.